# Can't get any data on camera image capture intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I am using FileProver and setting `MediaStore.EXTRA_DATA` in my intent but after adding `MediaStore.EXTRA_DATA` I am not getting any data on onActivityResult() method

```
    fun gridCaptureImage(position: Int) {
        val callCameraIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        }
//        callCameraIntent.putExtra("position", position)

        if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.packageManager)!=null) {
            val imageFile = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) createNewImageFile() else createImageBeforeLollipop()

            val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.kreeti.gogal.fileprovider", imageFile!!)
            callCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
            callCameraIntent.putExtra("position", position)
            (mContext as Activity).startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, GRID_VIEW_CAMERA_REQUEST)
        }
    }
```

This is my manifest file:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.kreeti.gogal.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This is provider_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I need the position to in the activity because I am setting data for the gridView. Besides that my image is not getting stored in the provided path. How do I solve this?

Comment: did you declared file provider in manifest?

Comment: I have added the part of xml in my question

Comment: `and setting MediaStore.EXTRA_DATA in my intent` ?? I dont see you doing that.

Comment: And where is your onActivityResult code?

Comment: Please tell the value of `imageUri.string`.

Comment: I'm getting the ImageUri as `"${applicationId}"/files/Pictures/${image_file_name}", but is not being shown in that folder when getting activity result